# port 443: connection refused when i use curl with google.androidapis.com php android

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging, connection-refused

I am developing a chat app using gcm on android studio and testing with a physical android device (not an emulator).  When I try to push notifications to the cloud using curl on PHP, I get the following error:

> port 443: connection refused

I have tried other ports like 5228 and 5229 but the same error still occurs. Here is  my code for the curl:

```
 include_once __DIR__ . '/../../include/Config.php';

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(GOOGLE_API_KEY.'Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

How could I fix this error?